# Why do I get " illegal instructions" error?

Tags: c++

This is the class

```
using namespace std;

class Animal
{
    public:

    Animal()
    {
        using std::cout;

        cout << "[+]Animal created...";
    }
  
    string makeSound(std::string name,std::string sound){
        
        using std::cout;
        
        cout<<name <<"goes"<<sound;
            
    }
        
    string eatsFood(std::string name,std::string food){
        
        using std::cout;

        cout<<name<<" eats " <<food;
    }
};
```

Here is the source file

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>

#include "animal.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{   
    Animal obj;
 
    obj.makeSound( "dog","woof! woof!");
 
    obj.eatsFood("dog"," Meat and vagitables");
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add `-Wall` and `-Werror` to your compiler options to avoid such problems.

Comment: `using std::cout; cout << "whatever\n";` is rather verbose. Just say `std::cout << whatever\n";`. And get rid of all those `using namespace std;`s.

Answer (score 3):

Your `makeSound` and `eatFood` function are declared as returning `string`s, but you are not actually returning from those functions. This invokes undefined behavior, and could result in an `illegal instruction` error.

If you make them `void` returning functions, you'll be fine. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6dfv4j).

Also, you shouldn't use `using namespace std;` especially in header files.

Comment: Thank you very much my code was compiled successfully

Comment: @SamuelLam No problem. Consider accepting the answer when you can. Also, compile with warnings such as `-Wall` and the compiler will tell you about these mistakes.